# Windows ListView LVM_GETITEM iImage is always zero

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I am trying to do some stuff with the desktop listview.  I can get the text of the item with LVM_GETITEM, but the iImage struct member is always zero, and so is the state.  I'm running Win 7 64 and compiled for 64 with Dev C++(gcc).  I also tried compiling it as 32bit and tested on XP with the same result...just text, image and state are assigned zero.  I can also get the item count no problem with ListView_GetItemCount().

```
HWND progman = FindWindow("progman", NULL);
HWND shell = FindWindowEx(progman, NULL, "shelldll_defview", NULL);
HWND hwndListView = FindWindowEx(shell, NULL, "syslistview32", NULL);
int ct = ListView_GetItemCount(hwndListView);

const DWORD dwBufSize = 1024;       
DWORD dwProcessID;
DWORD dwResult;
HANDLE hProcess;

BYTE *lpRemoteBuffer;

LVITEM lvItem = {0};

BYTE lpLocalBuffer[dwBufSize] = {0};

// Get the process id owning the window
::GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwndListView, &dwProcessID );

// Open the process wih all access (You may not have the rights to do this)
hProcess = ::OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessID );

// Allocate a buffer in the remote process
lpRemoteBuffer = (BYTE*)::VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, NULL, dwBufSize,
MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );

// Fill in the LVITEM struct, this is in your own process
// Set the pszText member to somewhere in the remote buffer,
// For the example I used the address imediately following the LVITEM stuct
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_IMAGE|LVIF_PARAM|LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.iItem = 0;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
lvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;

// Point to after LVITEM in the remote buffer
lvItem.pszText = (LPTSTR)(lpRemoteBuffer + sizeof( LVITEM ));

// Copy the local LVITEM to the remote buffer
::WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, (LPVOID)lpRemoteBuffer, &lvItem, sizeof(LVITEM), NULL );

// Send the message
::SendMessage( hwndListView, LVM_GETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)lpRemoteBuffer);

// Read the struct back from the remote process into local buffer
::ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (LPVOID)lpRemoteBuffer, lpLocalBuffer, dwBufSize, NULL );

//Fix pszText to point to same offset in local buffer
lvItem.pszText = (LPTSTR)(lpLocalBuffer + sizeof( LVITEM ));

MessageBox(hwnd, lvItem.pszText, "", 0);

char txt[10];
ZeroMemory(txt, 10);
MessageBox(hwnd, itoa(lvItem.iImage, txt, 10), "", 0);
MessageBox(hwnd, itoa((int)lvItem.state, txt, 10), "", 0);

// Clean-up
::VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, (LPVOID)lpRemoteBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE ); 
::CloseHandle( hProcess );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating virtual memory for text. You must also allocate virtual memory for `LVITEM`. Then assign the text memory to `lvItem.pszText`, and then read both memory. It has to be compiled 64-bit for 64-bit systems. Add more error checks.

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ |
     PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessID);

const DWORD dwBufSize = 1024;
void* pbuf = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, dwBufSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
void* pitem = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(LVITEM), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.iItem = 0;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
lvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
lvItem.pszText = (char*)pbuf;

WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pitem, &lvItem, sizeof(LVITEM), NULL);

if (SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_GETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LVITEM*)(pitem)))
{
    char buf[dwBufSize];
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pbuf, buf, dwBufSize, 0))
    {
        OutputDebugString(buf);
        OutputDebugString(", ");
        if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pitem, &lvItem, sizeof(LVITEM), 0))
        {
            _itoa_s(lvItem.iImage, buf, 10);
            OutputDebugString(buf);
            OutputDebugString("\n");
        }
    }
}

VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pitem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pbuf, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Comment: It turns out I don't need to do this anymore, but thanks for the help!  I'll vote for your answer.

Comment: That's probably for the best. Accessing the desktop with this method is not recommended.